# Retrieve value from DropDownList in nested GridView on RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, nested-gridview

I have a nested GridView(`GvMP_Summary_Items`). Each row contains a DropDownList. The DropDownList is bounded on the RowDataBound event of the nested GridView.

Each row also contains 1 Button. Upon pressing this button on the RowCommand event, I would like to find the current selected value of the DropDownList so I can use it further on in the code.

The code I have will only get the default value of the DropDownList on each row, which is currently set at `0` for each row.

Below is the RowCommand Event:

```
Protected Sub GvMP_Summary_Items_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

  Dim lb As ImageButton = CType(e.CommandSource, ImageButton)
  Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = lb.BindingContainer //Getting current row to get index       

  Dim GvMP_Summary_Items As GridView = CType(gvRow.FindControl("GvMP_Summary_Items"), GridView)

  Dim intMPItem_Qty As Integer = CType(gvRow.FindControl("cboMPItem_Qty"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
  Dim strMPItem_Qty As String = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtMPItem_Qty"), TextBox).Text

End Sub
```

I have even included a TextBox in the GridView row which default value is empty `""`. Although on the row if something is entered the on RowCommand event brings back the value with a comma(,) in front of it.

This proves that I am picking up the correct row and can retrieve a value from a TextBox but not a DropDownList.

Is there something I am missing? Why can I return a value entered in a TextBox but not the selected value of a DropDownList? Also why the comma(,) in front of the TextBox value?

**Note:** In above case code has been written using VB so answers in VB over C# but I can accept both.

Comment: How are you populating the dropdownlist? Is it possible you are clearing and refilling it on each postback resetting it to its default value?

Answer (score 3):

### Important things:

1. Bind parent GridView in **Page_Load** method
2. Bind child GridView in parent *GridView* 's **RowDataBound** event
3. Bind DropDownList in child *GridView* 's **RowDataBound** event
4. Add **CommandName** to the Button which is inside child GridView
5. Finally, in RowCommand event of child GridView

   - Get child *GridView* 's **row**
   - Then find all **controls** inside child GridView from child *GridView* 's **row**

I'm not so aware of VB.NET so I have added an example (C#) of Nested GridView with RowCommand event (hope OP can use it in VB.NET):

### HTML code (.Aspx):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Outer" OnRowDataBound="GridView_Outer_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outer Column1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_Outer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Label_Outer") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outer Column2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView_Inner" OnRowDataBound="GridView_Inner_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView_Inner_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inner Column1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_Inner" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Label_Inner") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inner Column2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Inner" Text='<%# Eval("TextBox_Inner") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inner Column3">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Inner" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inner Column4">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button_Inner" runat="server" CommandName="BtnInnerCmd" Text="Inner Button" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label_Result" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</form>
```

### Code-Behind (.Aspx.cs):

```
DataTable TempDT = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDataTable();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView_Outer.DataSource = TempDT;
        GridView_Outer.DataBind();
    }
}

// create DataTable
public void CreateDataTable()
{
    TempDT = new DataTable();
    TempDT.Columns.Add("Label_Outer");
    TempDT.Columns.Add("Label_Inner");
    TempDT.Columns.Add("TextBox_Inner");

    TempDT.Rows.Add("OuterLabel", "InnerLabel", "");
    TempDT.Rows.Add("OuterLabel", "InnerLabel", "");

    // store DataTable into ViewState to prevent data loss on PostBack
    ViewState["DT"] = TempDT;
}

// Calls Outer GridView on Data Binding
protected void GridView_Outer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if gridview row is not in edit mode
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Get Outer GrridView 's controls
        Label Label_Outer = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_Outer");
        GridView GridView_Inner = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView_Inner");

        // get DataTable from ViewState and set to Inner GridView
        GridView_Inner.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["DT"];
        GridView_Inner.DataBind();
    }
}

// Calls Inner GridView on Data Binding
protected void GridView_Inner_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if gridview row is not in edit mode
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Get Outer GrridView 's controls
        DropDownList DropDownList_Inner = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList_Inner");

        // Create a DataTable to Bind data for DropDownlist
        DataTable TempDDLDT = new DataTable();
        TempDDLDT.Columns.Add("ItemText");
        TempDDLDT.Columns.Add("ItemValue");

        TempDDLDT.Rows.Add("ItemText1", "ItemValue1");
        TempDDLDT.Rows.Add("ItemText2", "ItemValue2");

        // bind DataTable to the DropDownList
        DropDownList_Inner.DataSource = TempDDLDT;
        DropDownList_Inner.DataTextField = "ItemText";
        DropDownList_Inner.DataValueField = "ItemValue";
        DropDownList_Inner.DataBind();
    }
}

// Calls when Inner GridView 's button clicked
protected void GridView_Inner_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // get Inner GridView 's clicked row
    GridViewRow InnerGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

    // get Inner GridView 's controls from clicked row
    TextBox TextBox_Inner = (TextBox)InnerGridViewRow.FindControl("TextBox_Inner");
    DropDownList DropDownList_Inner = (DropDownList)InnerGridViewRow.FindControl("DropDownList_Inner");

    // check if correct button is clicked
    if (e.CommandName == "BtnInnerCmd")
    {
        string DropDownListValue = DropDownList_Inner.SelectedValue;
        string TextBoxValue = TextBox_Inner.Text;

        Label_Result.Text = "DropDownList 's Selected Value is " + DropDownListValue +
                            "<br />TextBox 's Entered Value is " + TextBoxValue;
    }
}
```

### Demo Image:

[image]
**Note:** Above DropDownList selects Selected Value not Text.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very easily by casting the `CommandSource` of the `RowCommand` back to a button and then get the correct row from that. Once you have the row you can use `FindControl` to locate the `DropDownList`. This works on every level of nested items and also on the top Control.

**VB**

```
Protected Sub GMP_Summary_Items_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    'cast the commandsource back to a button
    Dim btn As Button = CType(e.CommandSource,Button)

    'get the current gridviewrow from the button namingcontainer
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(btn.NamingContainer,GridViewRow)

    'use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist in that row
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(row.FindControl("cboMPItem_Qty"),DropDownList)

    'show the selected value of the dropdownlist
    Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue

End Sub
```

*Code was translated from C# with a [code translator](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/), so it may not be 100% accurate.*

**C#**

```
protected void GMP_Summary_Items_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the commandsource back to a button
    Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button;

    //get the current gridviewrow from the button namingcontainer
    GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist in that row
    DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("cboMPItem_Qty") as DropDownList;

    //show the selected value of the dropdownlist
    Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

> You do need to bind data to the GridView and the DropDownLists in an
>   `IsPostBack` check, otherwise the data will be rebound to the DDL on every PostBack and the selected value is lost